Return a string array from a C++ function to Fortran
I am struggling with filling a string array in a C++ code. Here is what I tried to do:
main.f90:

program main
    implicit none
    character(len=100) arr(3)
    call get_string_array(arr, 100, 3)
    write(*,'(3(a,3x))') arr
end

cpp_func.cpp:

#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

void ConvertToFortran(char* fstring, size_t fstring_len, const char* cstring)
{
    size_t inlen = strlen(cstring);
    size_t cpylen = min(inlen, fstring_len);

    fill(fstring, fstring + fstring_len, ' ');
    copy(cstring, cstring + cpylen, fstring);
}

extern "C"
{
  void get_string_array_(char** arr, int len, int n)
  {
      const char* strings[] = {"duma1", "duma2", "duma3"};
      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
          ConvertToFortran(arr[i], len, strings[i]);
  }
}

After compiling the two files as
ifx -c main.f90
icx -c cpp_func.cpp
ifx main.o cpp_func.o


I receive a segmentation fault. Could you please help me how to print array arr properly within main.f90?
*** Edit ***
Any solution which is able to pass a string array from C++ to Fortran would be appreciated.

You need to establish on which side of the fence the error is occuring, whether it is in Fortran or C++.  The C++ code by itself has nothing wrong with it provided that the pointers are valid and there is room to copy the characters into the buffer.

Are you certain that the array is represented as char*[3] and not as char[3][100]? In the latter case, you would receive a char* pointer pointing to a contiguous array of 300 characters.

@PaulMcKenzie The error is in the 4th line of the main.f90 file.

Is there a particular constraint you have which means you can't use the language interoperability features defined by Fortran? If you are relying on implementation-specific methods then you will need to provide us substantially more detail about the implementations and systems you are using.

@francescalus I would be happy with any working solutions, as well. Do you have one? I don't have any constraints, just that I need to fill my string array in C++ and pass to Fortran.

Have you checked existing resources?

@francescalus Do you have a recommendation for a concrete page? I saw these posts, but none of them seemed to be simple to implement.

I need to fill my string array in C++ -- Here is the problem with just saying this -- In the C++ code, all you have are pointers -- there are no arrays.  C++ is relying that the caller is passing in buffers that point to memory that can be written to.  It is the responsibility of the caller to ensure that what they are passing to C++ is what C++ is seeing.  You need to debug the code when it reaches the C++ side as to exactly what those addresses are, and whether they match up with what Fortran is sending.

Also, just as a test, fill the array in at the Fortran side with some sort of text, then call C++ to see if that same text shows up.  If you don't see that text on the C++ side, then you are not passing the "array" correctly, and thus your assumptions on how to pass arrays are way off.  My suggestions come with me not knowing anything about how Fortran passes parameters to C++ -- what I do know is if I am supposed to pass "x" from language A to C++, that "x" better show up on the C++ side, else I know I'm doing something wrong.

The first crucial thing is that you should be implementing the interactions between languages using C-interoperable interfaces ("bind(C)") and the second is to work out what the interoperable things are. If you can write using C interop with a clear statement of design goals, we'll be able to give more concrete advice.

Non-standard language interoperation, especially with characters, is a huge pain. Fortunately, it's no longer the 1970s, 1980s or 1990s.

Without trying to debug your code myself, I'd wonder whether you need pass-by-value for len and n. (Again: bind(C).)

@nneonneo In Fortran it is a contiguous array of 3 character strings, each 100 characters long. Provided that the compiler does not insert any byte padding between the array elements it would be 300 contiguous characters in memory.

@VladimirFГероямслава thanks for the clarification. In that case, it seems obvious that the OP needs to fill the contiguous array, and that attempting to treat it as an array of three char * pointers will crash. Should be an easy fix.

When was doing fortran-C interop, I strictly was avoiding text. Depending which compiler you use, string representation in Fortran was quite different from what C uses, most are using so-called pascal string - length and 8-bit data. Scalar data -that another thing, interoperability there was supported.

@Swift-FridayPie That's why C-interoperable Fortran procedures should uae arrays of single characters (strings of length one). There are no hidden arguments when bind(C) is used.

@VladimirFГероямслава bind(C) is new standard thing, the implementations I dealt with either had something else (e.g. Intel or Compaq-style binding) or were using assumed conventions

@Swift-FridayPie Sure, this was just an explanation, sort of even a supporting one. But also stressing that this is not an issue any more and text does not have to be strictly avoided since around the start of this century.

First, you should use the C binding features of Fortran, to have a more robust code:
program main
   use iso_c_binding
   implicit none
   character(len=100) arr(3)
   
   interface get_string_array
      subroutine get_string_array(a, len, n) bind(C)
         import c_int, c_char
         integer(c_int), value :: len, n
         character(kind=c_char,len=1) :: a(*)
      end subroutine
   end interface
   
   call get_string_array(arr, 100, 3)
   write(*,'(a)') arr
end

As you can see the interface of the C routine is described. In particular, len and n have the value attribute, because C passes the scalar objects by value. Regarding the character array, it is described in the interface as a flat 1D array of individual characters, because this is how the C side sees it with the char* declaration.
On the C side you don't have a lot of changes. char* instead of char**, and &arr[i*len] instead of arr[i]: for, to address the i-th string of the Fortran array, you have to address the (len*i)-th character in C.
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

void ConvertToFortran(char* fstring, size_t fstring_len, const char* cstring)
{
    size_t inlen = strlen(cstring);
    size_t cpylen = min(inlen, fstring_len);
    fill(fstring, fstring + fstring_len, ' ');
    copy(cstring, cstring + cpylen, fstring);
}

extern "C"
{
    void get_string_array(char* arr, int len, int n)
    {
        const char* strings[] = {"duma1", "duma2", "duma3"};
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            ConvertToFortran(&arr[i*len], (size_t)len, strings[i]);
        }
    }
}


Thank you very much your detailed implementation! I really appreciate what you provided, which of course works well. Hopefully this will be helpful for those who would like to see a simple example in this topic.
